# Firefox Refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML with following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doRefreshWithInterval() {
        setTimeout("doRefresh()", 60000 );
    }

    function doRefresh() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("Dashboard.jspa") >= 0) {
        doRefreshWithInterval();
    }
</script>
```

To make a page refresh periodically. The problem is when I scroll down the page (it is a long page), and refresh happens on some browsers (specially Firefox) the browser goes to top of the page and not where I was. Is there some way to prevent this, and make Firefox scroll down to the last position after refresh?

Comment: The non-string form of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) would be a better idea: `setTimeout(doRefresh, 60000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you only need to make one tiny change to your existing code. Change `document.location.reload(true);` to `document.location.reload();`.

Using `true` you force the browser to get the page from the server again, which means your place on it will be lost. When you remove the `true`, the browser loads the page from the cache, preserving your place on the page.

This may not be helpful, however, if the reason you're automatically reloading the page is to get the latest version of the page that the server may have modified.

Tested with Firebug in Firefox 12.0.

Comment: Don't you think an explanation of the difference would help the OP? Like maybe how using "true" grabs the page from the server instead of cache?

Answer (score 3):

A solution that comes to my mind is:

1. Before refresh, get the vertical position of the page
2. Store that number in a cookie
3. Refresh
4. On page load, see if there is a cookie for page position
5. Scroll to that position via script

Comment: Or, you could redirect to a URL that has a query parameter with the scroll position in it.  Would work even without cookies.

Comment: 2. - or store the scrollTop value in localStorage and 3. - on page load remove the value from localStorage after retrieving.

Comment: I would recommend to use localStorage since cookies are travelling through the network and changing of URL is undesirable.

Comment: How can I use localStorage between request?